# Passing a single value from a SQL query to a PowerShell variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to a single value from a SQL query to a PowerShell variable. I know the connection and query are running successfully because I am getting the output I expected when using Invoke-DbaQuery or Invoke-Sqlcmd.  But when I try to assign the query results to a variable, all I see is `System.Data.DataRow`

Any suggestions on how to get this query's results assigned to a variable?

```
$SQLInstance = "SQLInstance"
$Database = "DatabaseName"
$Query = "SELECT TOP (1) Password FROM dbo.Connections WHERE VendorName = 'YYY' ORDER BY VendorName;"

#Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -Query $Query

#$password = (Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -Query $Query)
$password = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Database $Database -Query $Query

Write-Host $password
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've seen that `$password` is a `[DataRow]`, and `Write-Host` can only use `[string]`. Try one of these two:

- Output the result by itself (no `write-host`). Powershell will format all of the fields and rows for you:

```
$password

# outputs:

password
--------
hunter2
```

- Output just the string from your query result instead of the table format above:

```
$password.Password

# Outputs:

hunter2
```

DataRow objects are made to contain multiple rows and multiple fields, so it can get confusing when you're expecting just a single value as a result.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - that worked for me.